# HTML JavaScript dynamic canvas components

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want an HTML5 page with a combo box for selecting components like “Circle, Rectangle, Square, Polygon, Triangle” and another combo box for selecting their coordinates,the pictures need to be redrawn on the screen based on the selected component and the coordinates given onclicking the button drawimage.

Comment: Please try to improve this question by showing us your best good faith attempt and by asking a much more specific question over just what confuses you. So please, give it a try.

Comment: I agree with @abarisone. Question needs to be specific with code for us to help. With your request, it looks like you might need to use canvas libraries. try looking into fabricjs. http://fabricjs.com/

Comment: yes, but besides canvas there could be even svg used, or predefined bitmap images, just displaying the correct ones... 
@OP please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in jquery example with onchange event when the user select an item from the first list, Vuillez change the values ​​of the second list, after that you can draw images jquery or by Kinetic by js example